# c# deep copy of 2 dimensional array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, deep-copy, dimensional

EDIT: because it was marked as duplicate I searched a little further and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects). So I made a Clone class and cloned each object separately and put it in my new array.

I have a 2 dimensional array of objects of which I would like to have a deep copy. So that when I use the original elements the copied don't change and vice versa.

Only answers I found consisted of 1 dimensional arrays or ints (which aren't self made objects).

```
A[,] Table = new A[5,5];
B[,] Copy = A; //this just contains references to A
```

Comment: what type of objects do these arrays contain? only value types like intergers, or real objects?

Comment: The objects are real objects, that is they are object from a class I wrote myself.